# A separate electricity counter exclusively for heating the basement?

Tags: electrical, heating

I got a recommendation to start heating the crawl space in the building, as simple as placing two heaters with thermostats on two exterior walls (the other two are attached to neighbouring units), putting them to 5°C (41°F), and leaving them on for the winter.

All units in the building are occupied by tenants. Is there a straightforward way to separate the cost for heating the crawl space and their electricity bills? Perhaps a separate electricity counter exclusively for heating the basement?

Comment: There's also another question here: what are you trying to prevent? Your interest in that temperature range suggests you are trying to prevent pipe freeze. There are cheaper ways to do that.

Comment: Yes heat trace on the plumbing covered with insulation would be much cheaper than heating the whole crawl space especially with electric heaters.

Comment: Primary purpose: reducing condensation on a dryer outlet tube that happens to go through there; secondary: slowing down wood beams rotting by hopefully having dryer air in the crawl space.

Comment: To stop condensation from forming on dryer run is a job for insulation not additional heat.  Wrap the dryer run with insulation that has a moisture barrier.  In the long run, it will be a whole lot cheaper and safer.  If you need to protect the lumber consider a coat of good quality paint.  Heating the space will not dry the air. For that put down a ground cover of 10mil plastic sheeting. And in spring, summer and fall vent the space.

Answer (score 2):

### "*Is there a way?*  It's mandatory!" - Suze Orman

(That question was about prepaying your taxes throughout the year).

This question is about how to meter what are **commons loads**, electric loads which serve not one single tenant, but all of them or the building itself.   Commons area loads are such as outdoor site lighting, the shared-usage washer/dryer, commons hallway and utility room heating, security system, garage gates, etc.

Most jurisdictions that have laws about this *require* that "commons area" loads be on separate metering from in-unit tenant loads.  This can either be on separate electric company meters paying separate bills, or on their own landlord-owned sub-metering, which yes, do exist as purchasable products.

The laws are either in the tenant protection laws, or in the building codes.  If the latter, then you may be "grandfathered" until you do serious work in that area, at which point you must comply woth modern code.

All of this is moot if you include electricity as part of the rent.  If the city nails you for a violation of these codes, most likely they would settle for you switching to that model.